# Add to an array - sub-document without duplicate field values

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to add an object to an array in MongoDB. I don't want it to be duplicated.

I am trying to update the user read array by using `$addToset` in `findOneAndUpdate`. However, it is inserting duplicate because of timestamp; the timestamp is an important property. I can't negate it. Can I insert based on key like `userId`? Please let me know.

```
{
    _id: 'ddeecd8b-79b5-437d-9026-d0663b53ad8d',
     message: 'hello world notification',
     deliverToUsersList: [ '123-xxx-xx', '124-xxx-xx']
    userRead: [
     {
       isOpened: true,
       userId: '123-xxx-xx'
       updatedOn: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
     },
     {
       isOpened: true,
       userId: '124-xxx-xx'
       updatedOn: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()
     }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to the field userId and enable 'Avoid duplicates' in index settings.
I use Robo3T client to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To add new objects without duplicate information into the `userRead` array, you have check for the duplicate information in the update method's query filter. For example, the following code will not allow adding new object with duplicate `userId` field value.

```
new_userId = "999-xxx-xx"
new_doc = { userId: new_userId, isOpened: true, updatedOn: ISODate() }

db.test_coll.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: 'ddeecd8b-79b5-437d-9026-d0663b53ad8d', "userRead.userId": { $ne: new_userId } },
   { $push: { "userRead" : new_doc } },
)
```